# set jquery date in spring mvc controller not working

Tags: jquery, spring-mvc

I have a spring mvc web application that uses jquery. I have manager to get a jquery date to bind into my controller on submit of a form however I cannot set the date in my controller and have it show in my jquery datepicker on load.

To get the jquery date to bind into my controller I had to do the following....

In my jquery I had to say...

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
      changeMonth: false,
      changeYear: false,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      showButtonPanel: false,
      onSelect: function() {
          $("#"+$(this).attr("data-target")).val( $(this).val());
      }
    });
```

Then in my controller I had to say...

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder webDataBinder) {
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    df.setLenient(false);
    webDataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(df, true));
}
```

Now I am trying to set a default date from my controller into my form like so...

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showForm(
        ModelMap model,
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest) throws ServletRequestBindingException {

    ShortsAndOversDailyForm t = new ShortsAndOversDailyForm();
    t.setStore("1");
    t.setWeekEndingDate(new Date());
    model.addAttribute("shortsAndOversDailyForm", t);
    return "shortsAndOversDaily";
```

But I can't get this to work. I'm thinking that I need to do the opposite of what I did when binding from the form to the controller. The problem is I can't think of what the opposite to this is?

Can someone please help me ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using JSP view, you can simply pass a string formatted time as model attribute and set it as the HTML text input value

```
@RequestMapping(..)
public String get(Model model,..) {
  DateFormat df = ..
  model.addAtrribute("timeNow", df.format(new Date());
  ...
}
```

Then in your JSP view

```
<input type="text" value="${timeNow}"/>
```

Comment: Sorry but this didn't work for me. I will update my original post to tell you what i did